# Generate XPath of a particular element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need help in creating an XSL that would generate an XPATH for it from an XML.

Input XML fed to the XSL would look something like below. Element tag would contain the name of the element for which Xpath has to be obtained. SampleXML would contain the XML from which the XPath has to be obtained from :

```
<XMLInput>
<Element>FirstName</Element>
<SampleXML>
    <Member>
        <MemberInfo>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <MiddleName>M</MiddleName>
            <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        </MemberInfo>
        <MemberAddress>
            <State>NY</State>
            <Country>USA</Country>
        </MemberAddress>
    </Member>
</SampleXML>
```

The XSL should output the XPath of the Element 'FirstName':

```
/Member/MemberInfo/FirstName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/XMLInput">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[name()=current()/Element]">
        <!-- generate a path up to - but not including - ancestor SampleXML -->
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*[not(descendant-or-self::SampleXML)]">
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might want to add a delimiter, in case there are several elements with the same name.